# Keeping lines identical

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I realize that this is probably too much to ask, but: sometimes one wants certain lines in a document to remain identical; might there be a way to link two lines such that changes to one are immediately also applied to the other?

Comment: I think you approach the problem at the wrong level. If you need identical lines, you are already doing it wrong. Consider using a format (TeX, Markdown) that can *include* another files, or use ... links to the same external document. IMHO. Hyper-text :)

Comment: You could definitely do this without vim, using sed/awk/grep and inotifywait in a script.

Comment: @VanLaser, what about a text where the same formula is discussed several times; you would want it to be visible each time.

Comment: Open a different buffer, that shows the formula? And just reference it multiple times in your text?

Comment: @VanLaser, yes, I think you are right.

Comment: That being said, I think it would be doable if you have some start-end special comment markers, and a `BufWrite` (?) event to sync all regions to the one where the cursor is.

Comment: (.. or better, where the last changes happened, in such a region). This could get hairy - it would be easier if you would have an "original region" and "copies - other regions - that must be kept in sync", so that you won't edit the copies, only the original region (which automatically updates the copies). But this would need 2 sets of delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

I think I agree with the comments suggesting that this is the wrong way to approach whatever problem you're *actually* trying to solve.

That said... You'd need to mark up the document in *some* fashion to do this. Here's a exceedingly simple proof-of-concept:

```
function! SyncLines()
  let pairs = []
  call cursor(1, 1)
  while search("//>", "eW") > 0
    let pattern = str2nr(strpart(getline("."), col(".")))
    if pattern > 0
      call add(pairs, [pattern, line(".")])
    endif
  endwhile

  for pair in pairs
    call setline(pair[1], getline(pair[0]) . "//>" . pair[0])
  endfor
endfunction
```

This works by scanning the document for `//>X` patterns. Where `//>X` appears, the function will replace the entire line with the contents of line `X` (plus the same `//>X` token so the process is repeatable).

Obviously this is brittle in a few ways:

- it moves the cursor and doesn't have a mechanism to restore the cursor to the old position, would be be needed in a more user-friendly implementation.
- it assumes the token sequence `//>` has no other useful meaning in the file; this should be configurable or maybe based on the value of the `comments` setting.
- it doesn't do anywhere near enough error or sanity checking; I didn't do anything more than a few quick tests to make sure it sorta-worked.
- it works on single lines only, not regions of lines
- it (most importantly) is not resilient to changes in the document moving the text and thus invalidating line numbers.

If I were going to implement this "for real," what I'd probably do is make the token sequence more complex, essentially allowing it to name a keyword. So I'd use `//!copyright` to mark up a line that was the *source* line (named "copyright") and `//>copyright` to denote the line that received the value of the "copyright" source line.

I'd probably also set it up so that if the token appears entirely on a line on its own, it would mean that the function should read or write the line immediately *after* the token, since that might be useful behavior.

In any event, once set up, you could wire this function into a pre-write or post-load autocommand, depending on your needs.